# Ubuntu Xenial time discrepancy with VM and Windows host

Tags: azure, ubuntu

I have 3 new fresh installs of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS xenial on Azure VM, in the system log I noticed I have a time discrepancy and the system is logging this ever 5 seconds.

Mar  5 17:57:57 server1 systemd[1]: snapd.refresh.timer: Adding 2h 17min 4.279485s random time.
Mar  5 17:57:57 server1 systemd[1]: apt-daily.timer: Adding 5h 14min 48.381690s random time.
Mar  5 17:57:57 server1 systemd[19425]: Time has been changed
Mar  5 17:57:57 server1 systemd[37054]: Time has been changed

I have stopped the two services: apt-daily.timer and snapd.refresh.timer, and the "Time has been changed" messages still persist.  It seems to be a time discrepancy between the VM and host system.  I am not sure how to address this.  I also have VMs of the same exact version that I installed over a month ago on Azure and they don't show this error.

Thanks for guidance on this

Comment: I'm also seeing this with the same Ubuntu version. Instance types Standard_A1_v2, Standard_DS12_v2, and Standard_DS3_v2 in Azure Canada Central. What is your instance type and location?

Comment: Found a decent explanation about this here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8c0a1026-0b02-405a-848e-628e68229eaf/i-have-a-lot-of-time-has-been-changed-in-the-journal-of-my-linux-boxes?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows  - but nothing I would consider a real solution, yet.